# Is it fine to use higher octane gasoline than what is recommended on the fuel cap sticker

Tags: mercedes-benz, gasoline, octane, c240

I've got a 2000 W202 Mercedes C240. It's got a V-shaped, six cylinder gasoline engine. On the fuel cap, it says RON 95 EN 228. And in the manual also it says "Use only Premium Unleaded petrol". I sometimes want to try RON 98 as it's imported from Europe and everybody praises it. But I don't know whether it would harm the engine. Does the manual mean at "at least" or it means what it says- "only, no lower, no higher"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "at least". You will not cause any damage by using the higher octane fuel. The reason for the RON 95 rating in the first place, this is the lowest octane rating you can run before you might start hearing pinging or pre-ignition.

Comment: Should probably add that it's pointless to do so, since a higher than necessary octane offers no benefit for some cost.

Comment: @Leliel - I completely agree, but the question was if the higher RON would cause damage to the engine, which it wouldn't. The OP was fixating on the word "only" in the manual.